# meteor typeahead addresspicker google not defined error

Tags: meteor, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement the package votercircle:meteor-typeahead-addresspicker.  I have added it to the library but when I go to create a new AddressPicker.

The code I have below is from the examples yet does not seem to work.  Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

var addressPicker = new AddressPicker();


Template.driversTemplate.rendered = function() {
    $('#address').typeahead(null, {
          displayKey: 'description',
          source: addressPicker.ttAdapter()
    });


};
}
```

In my routing file I have the following setup to load the dependencies.

```
    Router.route('/drivers',{
path:'/drivers',
template:'driversTemplate',
    onBeforeAction: function(){
        var A = IRLibLoader.load('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js');
        var B = IRLibLoader.load('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places');

        if(A.ready() && B.ready()){
            console.log("Loading Googles JS Scripts");
            this.next();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like AddressPicker has a dependency on another package - whatever one defines `google`. You might have to contact the package developer for resolution.

Comment: I have used that package in a project and it works.  Did you include the google maps js?  (you need to follow step 1 here: https://github.com/sgruhier/typeahead-addresspicker#without-a-google-map)

Comment: I am new to meteor and have never added an external script hat has not been in in a package already.  What is the best method for adding external scripts.  I had assumed that these would have been handled with the wrapper.  and in this case am I just added the google two scripts or all 4?

Comment: I have tried a few other things.  Still not getting there, I have updated my original question with the current code and picture of the current errors.  You help is resolving this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've implemented it using **version 1.0.0** of the address picker.  See the note below about package versions.

Setup:

```
meteor create 33273220
cd 33273220
meteor add votercircle:meteor-typeahead-addresspicker@=1.0.0
meteor add iron:router
```

33273220.html:

```
<head>
  <title>33273220</title>
  <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="main">
  {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="hello">
  Address: <input id="myAddressField" name="myAddressField" type="text" size="50">
</template>
```

33273220.js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.hello.onRendered(function(){
    addressPicker = new AddressPicker();
    $('input[name="myAddressField"]').typeahead(null, {
      displayKey: 'description',
      source: addressPicker.ttAdapter()
    });
  });

}

Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: "main"
});

Router.route('/', function(){
  this.render('hello');
});
```

Then add some css to make the typeahead look decent.  You can use the css provided in the demo for the meteor-typeahead package: https://github.com/sergeyt/meteor-typeahead/blob/master/demo/style.css

Or at a minimum:

```
.tt-dropdown-menu{
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.tt-suggestion:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}
```

**Note:**
Using version 1.0.0 of votercircle:meteor-typeahead-addresspicker will pull in version 0.10.5_14 of sergeyt:typeahead.  That combination works with the code I've provided.  Using the latest version of votercircle:meteor-typeahead-addresspicker (1.0.1, as of the time of this answer) will pull in version 0.11.1_6 of sergeyt:typeahead.  That combination did not work for me when I updated package versions.